# Orion and Rush - HTTPS notifications over port 443

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have been trying to set up an Orion instance which would support subscription notifications to HTTPS (using Rush), but the handling of this seems to be a bit incorrect. Setting the notification url to e.g. https://www.example.com/path/ ends up at Rush as www.example.com:443/path/.

This is unsafe and not up to standards, as such a request could actually avoid https by using the same port over http. In our company we have a proxy set up which refuses such requests as "Bad Request: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port". The same error comes up in the Rush consumer output, while direct curl requests to Rush without the port work ok. See this discussion for another argument that the current requests are incorrect: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/speaking-plain-http-over-an-ssl-enabled-server-port. Google refuses such requests as well.

Our proxy is set up to redirect any http requests to https, but these do not work either, as Rush does not seem to follow the redirects.

How can we avoid this issue? Modifying our proxy would be unsafe and not following standards, changing Orion would require recompiling from sources and changing Rush to remove the port would be a bit hacky. Any changes (like adding the port or removing/changing the protocol) to the notification URL do not help.

EDIT: The command to run Orion was:

```
/usr/bin/contextBroker -port 1026 -logDir /var/log/contextBroker -pidpath /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid -dbhost localhost -db orion -rush localhost:5001
```

Rush (v 1.8.3) was installed with default values and Orion was updated from v0.14.1 to v0.23.0.

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to include the command line command used to run Orion (e.g. the output of `ps ax | grep contextBroker`)? It is specially relevant the value of the `-rush` option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking at the post you linked and I'm a bit confused. Do you mean Rush you set the notification URL to:  https://www.example.com/path/ and it gets changed to https://www.example.com:443/path/ or to  http://www.example.com:443/path/? Maybe Rush makes the port explicit using the same protocol, but if it is using the HTTP protocol instead, it will mean the Context Broker is not setting the appropriate Rush headers (unless, checking the code in the CB it seems to do it properly). What of those situations do we have here?

Comment: The port gets added in Orion. If you look at [Orion http request code](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/56896ad075ad51aef4c95d5eb7317f9b931e1cf7/src/lib/rest/httpRequestSend.cpp), line 634, the port number gets appended, which is by default 443. Anyway, we have passed our deadline for usage of Orion, so this issue is not relevant for us anymore and sadly I cannot retrieve the exact environment that I was using and repeat my tests. If no one else has this issue and https notifications work properly for others, maybe we can abandon resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Since verion 1.7.0, Orion implements native HTTPS notifications (i.e. without needing Rush). This could help to solve the situation described in this question.